# Known suicides in "A Song of Ice And Fire"

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Besides the lately known suicide of

> King Tommen Baratheon/Lannister.

Is there any other suicide either in TV show or books? Please disregard the suicides of peasants and soldiers, just the "important" people.

Also, if it's known, how did that person kill him/herself?

Comment: "Important" is a broad term....

Comment: not at all, important is familiar or head of a house.

Comment: In a way, Qhorin Halfhand committed suicide.

Comment: Wanted to be killed (and be killed) is not suicide

Comment: The Targaryens seem to do it the most, but then again there is going to be *a lot* more history written about them.

Comment: Would "named people" work? I'm not sure how many peasants have names in that series.

Comment: It's best to limit it to those with a surname, or those who have had dialogue with a POV character. That should at least cover most of the relevant, yet limit it to a finite number. Especially given that there aren't actually that many mentions of direct suicide.

Comment: @Axelrod [Pate](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Pate_(novice)), and [Pate](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Pate_(Standfast)), and [Steely Pate](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Steely_Pate), and [Spotted Pate](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Spotted_Pate), and [Pate](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Pate_(Night%27s_Watch)) and [Pate](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Pate_(whipping_boy)) and the other [Pates](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Pate). So there's that.

Comment: @Mooz Over half of those guys are very important!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*[Note: This answer will be heavily based the materials presented in the main ASOIAF books and the other companion works.]*

Probably the only other "relevant" character to commit suicide was

> [**Ashara Dayne**](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Ashara_Dayne)

jumped from the top of one of the towers of Starfall, called the Palestone Sword, on the cliff atop the sea. The body was never recovered.

Who was rumored to be

> loved by Ned Stark. It is rumored that she committed suicide after after giving birth to a still-born child. The fan theory is that it was Ned's.

---

Other "important" (not common-folk or soldiers) I can find are:

- [Maester Cressen](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Cressen) in his service to Stannis attempted to kill Melisandre by poisoning a cup of wine. Once the cup was poisoned, he offered​ to share it with her, knowing that once they both drink they would both be dead. However, with the help of her magic necklace, Melisandre was able to survive.
- [Gael Targaryen](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Gael_Targaryen) committed suicide by drowning herself in the Blackwater Rush. The reason for her suicide was that she had been seduced and abandoned by a traveling singer, who had left her pregnant.
- [Aelora Targaryen](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aelora_Targaryen) was married to her twin brother, Prince Aelor. Aelora caused Aelor's death in a mishap, which left her mad with grief. Aelora took her own life after being attacked at a ball by three men.
- [Helaena Targaryen](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Helaena_Targaryen), at the age of twenty-one, jumped from her window in Maegor's Holdfast at sunset. She died on the spikes below, with her throat impaled.
- [Jaehaera Targaryen](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jaehaera_Targaryen) reportedly threw herself from Maegor's Holdfast (akin to that of her mother, Queen Helaena Targaryen) and was impaled on the spikes of the dry moat below. She lived for a half hour in agony before her death
- The wife of [Eustace Osgrey](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Eustace_Osgrey) committed suicide. This made Ser Eustace the last of his line.

and then probably the most famous/infamous was

- [**Aerion Targaryen**](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aerion_Targaryen) aka Aerion Brightflame died screaming after drinking a cup of wildfire, believing it would transform him into a dragon.

---

The last one I can think of is debatable depending on what actually happened but,

> Jaqen H'ghar, or at least *one* of the Faceless Men

drinks a poison when a debt is owed to the gods when

> Arya kills Meryn Trant

This is debatable because the said character is still shown to be alive, but there is no doubt a dead body to be accounted for...

Comment: That final character is debatable, as you say, for many reasons. First is the acknowledgement that it did not happen in the books at all, as described on the show, so we don't *really* have any idea what actually happens in that scene, and what's illusion magic or hallucination and whatnot. Secondly, whether a character is *dead* is very simple for most characters, but the Faceless Men make that kind of complicated, whether you take the books or the show's interpretation. In both, though, I wouldn't consider it suicide (that's my opinion, not fact).

Comment: It can be argued that Ser [Arys Oakhart](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Arys_Oakheart) died because he did a "suicide charge" towards [Areo Hotah](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Areo_Hotah)...[\[1\]](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Arianne_Martell#A_Feast_for_Crows).

Comment: What about Stannis's maester? I forget the name - the one who drinks what he knows is poison so that Mel will drink it too.

Comment: @user568458 Ahh, Cressen! Good one!

Comment: Prince Daemon Targaryen launched a suicide attack against his nephew Aemond Targaryen when he thought he had not other way of prevailing against Vhagar. He knew he would be killed, went along anyways. Kamikaze.

Comment: @user568458 You are right, I thought Mel forced him to drink but after rereading the passage he knew he would die.

Comment: Also Dickon Tarly, who chooses to be executed by dragon along with his father.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by @Skooba](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/144749/58193) covers the majority of these cases but I can think of a few more.

#### Maegor "The Cruel" Targaryen

Although it is unknown how exactly he died common belief is that he commited suicide.

> Maegor's response to this was slow and confused, and it seems that this series of betrayals—and perhaps even the loss of his mother's guidance—had left him, in his own way, as broken as Aenys. He called his loyal lords to King's Landing, but all that came were minor lords of the crownlands, who had little to marshal against the king's many enemies. It was late at night, during the hour of the wolf, when the remaining lords departed the council chamber, leaving Maegor to brood alone. **Early the next morning, he was found dead on the throne, his robes sodden with blood, his arms slashed open by the barbs of the Iron Throne.**
>   Thus ended Maegor the Cruel. **How he came to die is a matter of much speculation.** Though the singers would have us believe that the Iron Throne itself killed him, some suspect his Kingsguard, and others some mason whom the king had failed to kill and who knew the secrets of the Red Keep. **But perhaps even likelier is the suggestion that the king killed himself rather than suffer defeat.** Whatever the truth, it was a reign that ended in the only way it could after the six years of terror that Maegor had visited upon the realm. But his nephew's reign would do much to mend the deep wounds he had made in the Seven Kingdoms.
>   <sub>The World of Ice and Fire, The Targaryen Kings: Maegor I</sub>

#### Qhorin Halfhand

Although not technically suicide he persuades Jon to kill him to win favour from the wildlings.

> "I've told you the truth. Our garrons were failing, and Rattleshirt was close behind us. Qhorin told me to pretend to join the wildlings. 'You must not balk, whatever is asked of you,' he said. **He knew they would make me kill him.** Rattleshirt was going to kill him anyway, he knew that too."
>   <sub>A Storm of Swords, Jon IX</sub>

#### House of Black and White Visitors

Many people come to the House of Black and White to be given the gift and drink poison from the fountain.

#### Sky cell prisoners

> Tyrion's arms were too short to reach the plate, and he was not about to step that close to the edge. All it would take would be a quick shove of Mord's heavy white belly, and he would end up a sickening red splotch on the stones of Sky, **like so many other prisoners of the Eyrie over the centuries.** "Come to think on it, I'm not hungry after all," he declared, retreating to the corner of his cell.
>   <sub>A Game of Thrones, Tyrion V</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Selyse Baratheon hung herself.

Comment: Hey, Kate! Would you mind adding the source (any applicable quote) to this answer by any chance? Thanks!